# Model in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code

```
    /// <reference path="angular.min.js" />


var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {

  var employees = [{
    name: "Ben",
    dateOfBirth: new Date("November 23,1980"),
    gender: "Male",
    salary: 55000.788
  }, {
    name: "Sara",
    dateOfBirth: new Date("May 05,1970"),
    gender: "Female",
    salary: 68000
  }, {
    name: "Mark",
    dateOfBirth: new Date("August 15,1974"),
    gender: "Male",
    salary: 57000
  }, {
    name: "Pam",
    dateOfBirth: new Date("October 27,1979"),
    gender: "Female",
    salary: 53000
  }, {
    name: "Todd",
    dateOfBirth: new Date("December 30,1983"),
    gender: "Male",
    salary: 60000
  }];
  $scope.employees = employees;
  $scope.sortColumn = "name";

  $scope.reverseSort = false;
  $scope.sortData = function(column) {
    $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn == column) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
    $scope.sortColumn = column;
  }

  $scope.getSortClass = function(column) {
    if ($scope.sortColumn == column)
      return $scope.reverseSort ? 'arrow-down' : 'arrow-up';
    return '';
  }

});
```

I just want to ask that are employees,sortColumn and reverse sort are  separate models or they belong to one model and what are the   sortData and getSortClass in this files are they behavior in our model please explain...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where to start... The variables in your codeblock all belong to the `myController` controller you have defined. They are instantiated when the controller is invoked through the `$scope` dependency, as well as any injected dependencies there may be.

`sortData` and `getSortClass` are functions declared in the scope of your controller. You cannot access them from another controller unless you traverse angulars `$rootScope` or using a listener. As for *what* those functions do, @kapil yadav has given an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**SortData**, contains the column name from which you want to sort and the **reverseSort is a property** of current employee object, which is set to true once the sort order is descending ( binary 0 ).

getSortClass fetch the current sort order in binary format ( 0 or 1) and update the reverseSort property accordingly.